# Is "Exchange Plan 1" & "Microsoft Power Automate Free" licenses sufficient for our Power Automate service account?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, flow, exchange-online

I have a power automate scheduled flow which run each day, and which loop through a SharePoint custom list items and send emails to external users for each item. now the service account which the flow is running under has these licenses:

[image]

So, are those licenses sufficient for the service account? and will the service account be able to send around 50-100 emails per run?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Exchange Online (Plan 1) and Microsoft Power Automate Free licenses should be sufficient for the service account to send 50-100 emails per run.

The Exchange Online (Plan 1) license provides the service account with the ability to send email messages via Exchange Online, while the Microsoft Power Automate Free license allows the service account to use the Power Automate service to create and manage automated workflows, including sending emails.

However, please note that there may be some limitations in terms of the number of emails that can be sent per day or per hour, depending on the specific policies and settings configured by your organization.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but can you please advise what type of settings and policies that can prevent sending more than 100 emails? so i can check them? thanks

Comment: That depends on company policies, such as to overcome spam issue they set limit on sending emails, so you might want to check with IT team on that part to see if you can send such emails in one run

Answer (score 1):

Exchange Online Plan 1 and Microsoft Power Automate Free licenses will be sufficient for service account to use Power automate services as long as you are using standard connectors and actions supported by Microsoft for free.

If you want to use Premium or custom connectors, service account will require paid Power automate licenses. Check these links for more details about licensing:

1. [Power Automate pricing](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/)
2. [Types of Power Automate licenses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/power-automate-licensing/types)

---

Also, the service account should be able to send 50-100 emails per flow run without any issues as below is the throttling limits for the office 365 outlook connector (300 API calls per 60 seconds):

[image]

Check below documentations for more details about limitations of Power automate flows and Office 365 outlook connector:

1. [Limits for automated, scheduled, and instant flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config)
2. [Office 365 Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but can we expand those limitation if we use different license ?

Comment: also what happen if the flow will do more than 300 calls per minute inside the flow? will the flow fail? or it will fail safe and retry to do extra calls after 60 minutes?

Comment: You can extend the limitations of power automate flows by purchasing higher licenses. To extend limitations of outlook connector, you can try creating & using multiple "connections" for same service account. But ideally 300 API calls/minute should be enough during a flow run.

Comment: It will hit throttling limit and flow will retry running the action. Also, limit is for 60 **seconds** and not minutes.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, so the power automate can handle more than 300 calls to outlook connector but it can take more than 60 seconds since it will retry any failed calls, am i correct?

Comment: We don't know how retry mechanism (when or how many times it will retry) works *internally* in Power automate service. But, it should handle up to 300 calls in 60 seconds. Also, I don't think more than 300 email actions will be fired in a power automate flow run within 60 seconds. So, it should work for your scenario.

Comment: Hi @microsoftdeveloperdesigner, does my below response answers your question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.  It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.